# refresh wicket container via ajax / collapsible ListView

Tags: java, ajax, listview, refresh, wicket

I have a ListView which shows some panels. Because this ListView can be long, I want to make it collapsible.

For this purpose I added a WebMarkupContainer:

```
final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("listViewContainer");
wmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
this.add(wmc);
```

This is how the ListView is created:

```
final ListView<String> examListViewSignedUp = new ListView<String>("examLVsu", signedUpExams) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2828116887162006658L;
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
        String examId = item.getModelObject();
        item.add(new ExamPanel("exam1", examId));
    }

};

wmc.add(examListViewSignedUp);
```

Finally, I add the AjaxLink. That is, in fact, a "[-]" if the list is expanded and a "[+]" otherwise. I "expand"/"collapse" the ListView by setting it's visibility via `.setVisible(...)`.

```
final Model<String> sulink = new Model<String>(esuclt);
wmc.add(new AjaxLink("overviewCollapseLinkSignedUp") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8603181768552484977L;
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (examListViewSignedUp.isVisible()) {
            examListViewSignedUp.setVisible(false);
            sulink.setObject("[+]");
        } else {
            examListViewSignedUp.setVisible(true);
            sulink.setObject("[-]");
        }
        target.add(wmc);
    }
}.add(new Label("oclt1", sulink)));
```

Markup:

```
<wicket:container wicket:id="listViewContainer">
        <h1 class="ocl">
            <a wicket:id="overviewCollapseLinkSignedUp" href="#"><span wicket:id="oclt1">[?]</span></a>&nbsp;
            <wicket:message key="examsHeadingInOverviewSignedUp">Exams - Signed Up</wicket:message>
        </h1>
        <span wicket:id="examLVsu"> <span wicket:id="exam1"></span></span>
</wicket:container>
```

My problem now is that the MarkupContainer isn't refreshed when clicking on the link. Nothing happens, but when I then reload the page, everything looks as expected. I searched for similar problems, but I wasn't able to find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update `<wicket:container>`'s via Ajax, since they are not present in the final markup.

Use a normal `<div wicket:id="listViewContainer">` instead.